# Chinese input doesn't work outside "Activities system search" (super key) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ibus, input-method, chinese

I use Ibus and both Chinese (Pinyin) and Chinese (Chewing), but it seems not working outside "Activities system search" (`super` key).
When I want to type Chinese chars outside "Activities system search", it always turns out to be English chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem! I used fcitx previously and decided to switch to use IBus after upgrading to 18.04. However the Chinese input only worked for system search and did not work for any other applications.

I fixed it eventually by uninstalling fcitx.

```
sudo apt-get remove fcitx
sudo apt-get purge fcitx
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Other things to note (just in case you haven't checked them) are

1. add Chinese to "language support", and
2. set keyboard input method system to be IBus.

This is a screenshot of the language-support dialog:

[image: screenshot-language-support]

祝好运!

Comment: It works for me! The third step would be reboot your computer.  I have tried restart ibus or logout but they didn't take any effects.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. Chinese input works only in "Show Applications" screen and not any other applications. I tried fcitx previously and I've completely removed it since. Also tried wiping .xinputrc and generate a new one with im-config.

It's likely some left-over config somewhere. My system was recently upgraded from 18.04 to 19.04. The original installation was a 12.x. It has been upgraded several times over the years.

Update: This issue is now fixed on my PC. I started up a ubuntu lxc container, installed ibus, and then replaced my /etc/X11/Xsession.d with the fresh copy from the container. Rebooted and all good now. The original directory contained a bunch of files from previous installations. Here is what I have now after the "reset":

```
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      3730 2018-12-14 20:33 Xsession
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-04-28 19:26 Xsession.d/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      2030 2018-12-14 20:33 Xsession.d/20x11-common_process-args
-rw-r--r-- root/root       878 2017-01-20 15:52 Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources
-rw-r--r-- root/root       389 2017-01-20 15:52 Xsession.d/35x11-common_xhost-local
-rw-r--r-- root/root       187 2017-01-20 15:52 Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1568 2017-01-20 15:52 Xsession.d/50x11-common_determine-startup
-rw-r--r-- root/root       146 2018-12-14 20:33 Xsession.d/60x11-common_localhost
-rw-r--r-- root/root       991 2019-03-12 20:56 Xsession.d/60x11-common_xdg_path
-rw-r--r-- root/root       629 2017-01-20 15:52 Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent
-rw-r--r-- root/root       166 2017-01-20 15:52 Xsession.d/99x11-common_start
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1062 2018-12-05 09:09 Xsession.d/20dbus_xdg-runtime
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1541 2018-08-03 21:18 Xsession.d/70im-config_launch
-rw-r--r-- root/root       743 2019-03-18 04:06 Xsession.d/55gnome-session_gnomerc
-rw-r--r-- root/root       752 2018-12-05 09:09 Xsession.d/75dbus_dbus-launch
-rw-r--r-- root/root       513 2018-12-05 09:09 Xsession.d/95dbus_update-activation-env
-rw-r--r-- root/root       335 2019-03-17 05:55 Xsession.d/90qt-a11y
-rw-r--r-- root/root       880 2018-12-15 13:18 Xsession.d/90gpg-agent
```